# add_format not working as expected with xlsxwriter

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

I'm trying to add a Title to an excel file, using pandas and xlsxwriter

The worksheet.merge_range merge_format isn't working as expected.

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(pd.json_normalize(data))
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("teste12.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=nome_tabela, index=False, startcol=0, startrow=5)
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(writer)
merge_format = workbook.add_format()
merge_format.set_border(True)
merge_format.set_bold(True)
merge_format.set_align("center")
merge_format.set_align("vcenter")
merge_format.set_font_size(20)
worksheet = writer.sheets[nome_tabela]
worksheet.merge_range(0,0,3,6,"Test", merge_format)
writer.save()
```

I also tryed using the merge_format as the documentation example:

```
merge_format = workbook.add_format({
'bold': 1,
'border': 1,
'align': 'center',
'valign': 'vcenter',
'fg_color': 'yellow',
'font_size' : 20})
```

In both cases the bold, border and align work as intended.
The font_size, valign and fg_color don't work.

[image]

What am I doing wrong ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are overwriting the workbook created by Pandas with a new workbook created by `xlsxwriter.Workbook()`.

The correct way to get the Pandas created workbook is shown in [Working with Python Pandas and XlsxWriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html) and in the working example below:

```py
import pandas as pd


nome_tabela = 'Sheet1'

df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [10, 20, 30, 20, 15, 30, 45]})

writer = pd.ExcelWriter("teste12.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=nome_tabela, index=False, startcol=0, startrow=5)

# Get the Pandas created workbook.
workbook  = writer.book
merge_format = workbook.add_format()

merge_format.set_border(True)
merge_format.set_bold(True)
merge_format.set_align("center")
merge_format.set_align("vcenter")
merge_format.set_font_size(20)

worksheet = writer.sheets[nome_tabela]

worksheet.merge_range(0, 0, 3, 6, "Test", merge_format)
writer.save()
```

**Output**:

[image]